# How to extend protocol Optional, where Wrapped item is Array of Equatable generic elements?

Tags: swift, protocols

I would say this problem is about proper declaration of extension.

I would like to extend Array filled with generic Elements, where Element conforms to Equatable. I've managed to do that by :

```
    extension Array where Element: Equatable{
        // my code
    }
```

However I'd like to know how to properly declare extension when the Array filled with Equatable elements is inside an Optional? I know that in this case I am actually extending protocol Optional, but I can't figure out the rest

I was thinking something like:

```
    extension Optional where Wrapped: Array  & Equatable {
      // my code
    }
```

Can't figure it out.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cristik provided a good solution. An alternative is to write an extension to an optional *collection* of equatable elements:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: Collection, Wrapped.Element: Equatable {
    func foo() { }
}
```

This would be applicable to arrays, array slices, and other collections.

Depending on what the extension does, you may want to use  a combination of `Collection`, `MutableCollection`, `BidirectionalCollection`, `RandomAccessCollection`.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can't specify this constraint at the extension level, however you should be able to specify it at the function level:

```
extension Optional {
    func myFunc<T: Equatable>() where Wrapped == [T] {
        // do your thing
    }
}
```

Comment: That would apply to an array of optionals, not to an optional array. Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Using your idea, it would be `extension Optional { func myFunc<T: Equatable>() where Wrapped == [T] { /* ... */ } }`

Comment: @MartinR you're right, I misread the`Array filled with Equatable elements is inside an Optional` part. I updated the answer.

Comment: @MartinR You are right. What about this: https://gist.github.com/eonist/dfa1412dc70eb93b2c516b35dd0daa1c if looked at some of the other suggestions to do extensions on arrays with optional arrays, but the solutions often add a lot of cruft

Comment: @eonist: Is this meant as a reply to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54261472/1187415?

Comment: @MartinR Ahh, nice! much cleaner.  Taking it even further, I wonder if it is possible to do this with a variable instead of a function. I updated the gist to reflect the design in the link you mentioned.