# Wrapping a generic method in a class extension

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm trying to wrap the generic Array method `compactMap` inside an Array extension to give the purpose of the method more meaning/readability. I'm simply trying to take an Array of Optionals and remove any and all `nil` values from it.

```
extension Array {
    public func removeNilElements() -> [Element] {
        let noNils = self.compactMap { $0 }
        return noNils // nil values still exist
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that `compactMap` here is not working. `nil` values are still in the resulting Array `noNils`. When I use the `compactMap` method directly without using this wrapper, I get the desired result of an Array with no `nil` values.

```
let buttons = [actionMenuButton, createButton]   // [UIBarButtonItem?]
let nonNilButtons = buttons.compactMap { $0 }    // works correctly
let nonNilButtons2 = buttons.removeNilElements() // not working
```

Am I not designing my extension method correctly?

Comment: Interesting question. I don't know how to fix this!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to define the method for an array of *optional* elements, and the return type as the corresponding array of non-optionals. This can be done with a generic function:

```
extension Array {
    public func removingNilElements<T>() -> [T] where Element == T?    {
        let noNils = self.compactMap { $0 }
        return noNils
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let a = [1, 2, nil, 3, nil, 4]   // The type of a is [Int?]
let b = a.removingNilElements()  // The type of b is [Int]
print(b) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

In your code, `$0` has the (non-optional) type `Element`, and it just wrapped by the compiler into an optional in order to match the argument type of `compactMap()`.

Comment: Shouldn't `removeNilElements()` be something like `removingNilElements()`? https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#name-according-to-side-effects

Comment: @BenLeggiero: Yes, that would be a better name.

Comment: You can also do this on the extension level: `extension Array where Element == Optional<Any> {..}`

Comment: @eonist: Yes, but then you lose all type information. You have to declare `a` as `[Any?]` and the return value has type `[Any]`.