# Array extension where Element is Optional and the the return type is Wrapped

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, option-type

I would like to create an array extension where the Element of the array is optional and the return type of the method is the non-optional Element Type.

Is it possible, and if so what would be the syntax?

The main idea is this in pseudo code:

```swift
extension Array where Element: Optional {
  func foo() -> ReturnType<Wrapped<Element>> {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54261341/1187415

Comment: What do you mean? you want to remove optionals from your array without changing their index? If anything could possibly be **nil**, It must be optional. So want exactly you try to achieve

Comment: Do you mean something like `compactMap`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean with `Wrapped<Element>` but since you need to return something why not use a closure for the return value, like this function to get the element at a specific index

```
extension Array  {
    func value<T>(at index: Int, emptyAction: () -> T) -> T where Element == T? {
        if let value = self[index] {
            return value
        }
        return emptyAction()
    }
}
```

Example

```
var test = [String?]()
test.append("ABC")
test.append("DEF")
test.append(nil)

for i in 0..<test.count {
    print(test.value(at: i, emptyAction: { "<empty>" }))
}
```

Outputs

```
ABC   
DEF  
<empty>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried something similar, but didn't know that I can use the `==` for types also.