# Extend an Array of Optional Equatables?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, protocols

I'd like to write an extension for operating on an array of optional values that conform to `Equatable`, for example:

```
class Bar: Equatable { ... }

let bar1 = Bar()
let bar2 = Bar()
let bars: [Bar?] = [ bar1, bar2, nil ]
bars.foo() <-- this guy
```

Is there a way to do this with Swift? I've tried many variations similar to this:

```
extension Array where Element == Optional<Equatable> {
    func foo() { ... }
}
```

and I understand why `Equatable` isn't happy, but is there a way around it?

I've found this question which is very similar: [How to extend protocol Optional, where Wrapped item is Array of Equatable generic elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54143757/how-to-extend-protocol-optional-where-wrapped-item-is-array-of-equatable-generi) but I need optional elements, not an optional array.

Comment: The problem you're having is that there is no such thing as an Optional Equatable. It has nothing to do with arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can't do:

```
extension Array where Element == Optional<Equatable>
```

But you can create a generic function in the `Array` extension:

```
extension Array {
    func foo<T: Equatable>() where Element == Optional<T> {
        ...
    }
}
```